# in reactjs how to get dynamic rows on selecting a dropdown value

Tags: reactjs

for example, I have 1 to 25 values in a drop-down, now in a table row, I need to display years from current year to currentyear+25 using reactJS

Comment: based on drop-down value i.e., if a dropdown value is 10 then I need to show 2018  to 2028  in table row

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us what you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: I don't get it, an example might help. I guess `getDerivedStateFromProps()` will do the job

Comment: https://capbud-prototype.herokuapp.com/capbud-newproject-step2.html. plz refer this link and u can see no of years=10 so that its below table showing 2017-2026, now if change to no of years=15 then the table should show 2017-2031, hope u get

Comment: any answer from anyone plz